react-tree-orgchart webpart is not running
enter image description here
enter image description here
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-tree-orgchart followed this github repo
reproduce steps -> cloned this repo and run the npm i
after running npm i getting this issue
It gets run and show the webparts into the workbench
